# SOAP Web service valued zeroed out on return

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

This is a really strange problem, and I'm just trying to think of things that I haven't tried yet. It is a very nuanced issue, but I'll try to provide as much information as I can.

I have a web service that that contains a function which takes an object representing an Order and then returns shipping rates for that order. I have confirmed via Fiddler that the response that the server is returning does contain the expected rate values. However, for some reason, after making the API call, the object generated from the web service always contains a value of 0 for all rates. So, it looks like the problem must have something to do with how the XML being returned by the web service is being deserialized.

The object that is returned is an array of objects representing shipping rates, and the weird thing is that most of the other values of the ShippingRate object have retained their value. One difference is that this is a decimal field and the others are strings, but I wouldn't think that would cause this to happen.

Another weird thing is that this only happens on this one site and only on the live site. It doesn't happen on our development server, even though the data in the database and the files on the site are virtually identical. I also tested on the live site of a different customer who users our shopping cart software, and there was no issue.

So, I realize that it is impossible to really know exactly what is going on just from this description, but I'm wondering if anybody else has had similar issues with deserialization and web services. In all honesty, I do not have that much experience with web services.

I can post any other information that would be helpful.

**Update:**

One very important detail I forgot to mention (though it is implied by one of the tags) is that I am using .NET.

Also, something else that I realized recently is that it is not just the Rate field that isn't blanked out. It is also all of the values that are after that alphabetically, though the ones before it return as expected. So, it looks like there is something is happening at that point in the deserialization process, though I'm not sure how to debug this.

The one thing about this that is really weird is that it is only happening on that one server (not on our virtually identical dev server), so it would seem like it is a server issue, but the XML response that comes back is correct (and essentially identical) in both cases (which would indicate that the problem is NOT on the server).

Comment: Can you post some code how you are consuming the web service? Are you hitting any exception? Is the call timing out?

Comment: I added some updated info. I don't know what code would really be useful. The reference file created by the WSDL is massive, so I can't post the whole thing, and I don't know if the code that is consuming the service would really be helpful. And, no, it is not throwing an exception or timing out.